# split_lib dependencies error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been facing this error for a long time and am perplexed as to how to get rid of it.
Here is a snippet of app level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the error that I am getting:
[image: This is the error that I am getting]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the error as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to solve it. 
The problem was due to the instant run enabled. I turned it off and it worked for me